# How to only display data from another cell that meet certain criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets here.

In sheet 2, I want to only display rows that meet one of two criteria.

```
1) sum of columns (P~X) and Z is equal to 4 AND column Y = 0

 OR

2) column AA = 1 AND column Y = 0
```

I tried following but failed

```
=FILTER(sheet1!B2, Sum(sheet1!P2:X2,sheet1!Z2) = 4,  sheet1!Y2=0)  OR  FILTER(sheet1!B2, sheet1!AA2=1, sheet1!Y2=0)
```

In the function above, `sheet1!B2`, but I want to display the entire tow if the condition is met.

Comment: Post sample data and then show your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Filter Data

```
=LET(data,Sheet1!A2:AD21,
    a,CHOOSECOLS(data,25)=0,
    b,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data,VSTACK(SEQUENCE(9,,16),26)),
        LAMBDA(r,SUM(r)=4)),
    c,CHOOSECOLS(data,27)=1,
FILTER(data,a*(b+c)))
```

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:AA8,BYROW(P2:AA8,LAMBDA(z,AND(OR(SUM(CHOOSECOLS(z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11))=4,CHOOSECOLS(z,12)=1),CHOOSECOLS(z,10)=0,CHOOSECOLS(z,10)<>""))))
```

or to avoid zero's instead of blanks:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(Sheet1!B2:AA8,BYROW(P2:AA8,LAMBDA(z,AND(OR(SUM(CHOOSECOLS(z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11))=4,CHOOSECOLS(z,12)=1),CHOOSECOLS(z,10)=0,CHOOSECOLS(z,10)<>"")))),IF(x="","",x))
```

Result:

[image]